# Await / Async in button event to call API

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save data to firebase after a form is completed in ASP.NET. The issue is trying to get it to await on the button click.

I have tried adding async to the event, but an error message comes up saying

> 'An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle.'

```
public async Task AddCompany(string companyname)
{
    await firebaseClient
        .Child("Company")
        .PostAsync(new Company() { CompanyName = companyname});
}

protected async void btnSign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await AddCompany(txtCompany.Text)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Async="true"` into aspx file. Like this

```
<%@ Page Async="true"  Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="GizmosAsync.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebAppAsync.GizmosAsync" %>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45

Comment: Thanks, but now I get a Parser Error: Parser Error Message: Error parsing attribute 'page': Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.Page' from its string representation '' for the 'Page' property. Line 1:  <%@ Page Async="true" Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SignUpPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="SearchAdamWeb.SignUpPage" %>

Comment: @Vernon007 You wrote `Page` two times `Page Async="true" Page Language="C#"`

Comment: Oops, I should I have realised that the 'page' stays there. Thanks its worked and helped me out with another problem in retrieving email/password info for a different page. Glad it was a quick fix.